# How can I show a tooltip on a disabled button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If you have a disabled button on a winform how can you show a tool-tip on mouse-over to inform the user why the button is disabled?

Comment: it would really be nice if the functionality was changed such that the tooltip was still shown when disabled. What better time to help the user out! Ive decided to leave the button enabled and just show a msgbox to explain why the action wont be taken. yuk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sam Mackrill, thanks for your answer, great idea to use the Tag to know what Control you are leaving. However you still need the IsShown flag as per BobbyShaftoe's answer.  If you have the mouse in the wrong spot, if the ToolTip comes up under it, it can fire another MouseMove event (even though you did not physically move the mouse).  This can cause some unwanted animation, as the tooltip continually disappears and reappears.

Here is my code:

```
    private bool toolTipShown = false;
    private void TimeWorks_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var parent = sender as Control;
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            if (ctrl.Visible && toolTip1.Tag == null)
            {
                if (!toolTipShown)
                {
                    var tipstring = toolTip1.GetToolTip(ctrl);
                    toolTip1.Show(tipstring.Trim(), ctrl, ctrl.Width / 2, ctrl.Height / 2);
                    toolTip1.Tag = ctrl;
                    toolTipShown = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ctrl = toolTip1.Tag as Control;
            if (ctrl != null)
            {
                toolTip1.Hide(ctrl);
                toolTip1.Tag = null;
                toolTipShown = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any resource issues with this getting fired for every mouse move?

Comment: Doesn't work when the control is within a TabControl. GetChildAtPoint() returns the TabControl instead of the child.

Comment: @PeterSmartt: the condition you described happened only to me when the `parent` control has a toolTip itself, otherwise the code from @SamMackrill just worked fine for me.

@flixfe: if your working with TabControl, you could do something like `if (ctrl.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(typeof(TabControl))) ctrl = ((TabControl)ctrl).SelectedTab;` in order to get the currently selected tab.

Comment: After trying for several hours I couldn't find a satisfying solution in my case. I finally solved my problem with a `MessageBox`. However I think in certain cases the ToolTip as proposed is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 15):

Place the button (or any control that fits this scenario) in a container (panel, tableLayoutPanel), and associate the tooltip to the appropriate underlying panel cell.  Works great in a number of scenarios, flexible.  Tip: make the cell just large enough to hold the bttn, so mouseover response (tooltip display) doesn't appear to "bleed" outside the bttn borders.

Comment: Nice idea, means you double your control count though,

Comment: Hey @SamMackrill (sry for late response, but for posterity), true dat, but should only be for the ctrls that require it (usu just a couple)avoids a lot of unnecessary code/complexity, leaves the implementation visual so non-developers (e.g. designers) can implement/maintain.  Might be kinda handy to create custom crtls already config'd this way as a pkg.

Comment: This is by far the most elegant answer. If you need the tooltip over a TableLayoutPanel cell, you will have to place a panel in the cell, then your control in the panel, as TableLayoutPanel cells cannot be referenced- only their contained controls.

Comment: I added the tooltip to the GroupBox containing the disabled button(s). This means the tooltip pops up whenever the user hovers anywhere near the disabled button, but I don't think that will be a problem.

Comment: Sounds like u may have the "bleeding" issue from tip in my answer; make sure the containing panel is no larger than the disabled bttn.

Answer (score 12):

I have since adapted BobbyShaftoe's answer to be a bit more general

Notes:

- The MouseMove event must be set on the parent control (a panel in my case)

  ```
  private void TimeWorks_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      var parent = sender as Control;
      if (parent==null)
      {
          return;
      }
      var ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
      if (ctrl != null && !ctrl.Enabled)
      {
          if (ctrl.Visible && toolTip1.Tag==null)
          {
              var tipstring = toolTip1.GetToolTip(ctrl);
              toolTip1.Show(tipstring, ctrl, ctrl.Width / 2, ctrl.Height / 2);
              toolTip1.Tag = ctrl;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          ctrl = toolTip1.Tag as Control;
          if (ctrl != null)
          {
              toolTip1.Hide(ctrl);
              toolTip1.Tag = null;
          }
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: small cosmetic correction: in your second if, you might want to add the condition `&& !ctrl.Enabled`, in order to make it disappear correctly when switching rapidly to another child control that is actually active (needs a special layout to be reproducable I think).

Answer (score 8):

So assuming your control is called `button1` you could do something like this.
You have to do it by handling the `MouseMove` event of your form since the events won't be fired from your control.

```
bool IsShown = false;      

void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Control ctrl = this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);

   if (ctrl != null)
   {
       if (ctrl == this.button1 && !IsShown)
       {
           string tipstring = this.toolTip1.GetToolTip(this.button1);                 
           this.toolTip1.Show(tipstring, this.button1, this.button1.Width /2, 
                                                       this.button1.Height / 2);
           IsShown = true;
       }
   }
   else
   {
       this.toolTip1.Hide(this.button1);
       IsShown = false;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had many GroupBox controls on my form, each of which contained numerous controls.  The code below is what I had to use to get the tooltip to show directly over disabled TextBox controls.

In Form1_Load event use:

```
AddHandler GroupBox1.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
AddHandler GroupBox2.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
AddHandler GroupBox3.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
AddHandler GroupBox4.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
AddHandler GroupBox5.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
AddHandler GroupBox6.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
AddHandler GroupBox7.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
AddHandler GroupBox8.MouseMove, AddressOf GroupBoxMouseMove
```

The stand alone method is:

```
Private Sub GroupBoxMouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim parent = TryCast(sender, Control)
    If parent Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim pt As New System.Drawing.Point
    pt.X = MousePosition.X - sender.left
    pt.Y = MousePosition.Y - sender.top - 22
    TextBox18.Text = pt.X
    TextBox20.Text = pt.Y
    Dim ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(pt)
    If ctrl IsNot Nothing AndAlso ctrl.Enabled = False Then
        If ctrl.Visible AndAlso ToolTip1.Tag Is Nothing Then
            Dim tipstring = ToolTip1.GetToolTip(ctrl)
            ToolTip1.Show("Show this text over disabled textbox.", ctrl, ctrl.Width \ 2, ctrl.Height \ 2)
            ToolTip1.Tag = ctrl
        End If
    Else
        ctrl = TryCast(ToolTip1.Tag, Control)
        If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
            ToolTip1.Hide(ctrl)
            ToolTip1.Tag = Nothing
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```