# Tooltip doesn't work with button that is set enable=false

Tags: c#

I render the buttons on a window form and there are some of them that I set enable = false.
But I want the tooltip still works for every button even if it's unenable. How could I do that?

Please help.

Comment: You need to paste the code with the Problem so that you can get help quickly

Comment: I guess that is by design

Comment: I just add button to my form and use oTip.SetToolTip(oButton, showText);

Comment: Yes, this is a bydesign behaviour. I've posted a workaround as solution.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491267/how-can-i-show-a-tooltip-on-a-disabled-button

Comment: The enabled buttons are working normally except the unenabled buttons that the tooltip doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the MouseMove event and then display the tooltip programmatically.
toolTip1 is your form tooltip obviously

```
private bool toolTipShown = false;
private void Control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = sender as Control;
    if (parent == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        if (ctrl.Visible && toolTip1.Tag == null)
        {
            if (!toolTipShown)
            {
                var tipstring = toolTip1.GetToolTip(ctrl);
                toolTip1.Show(tipstring.Trim(), ctrl, ctrl.Width / 2, ctrl.Height / 2);
                toolTip1.Tag = ctrl;
                toolTipShown = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ctrl = toolTip1.Tag as Control;
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            toolTip1.Hide(ctrl);
            toolTip1.Tag = null;
            toolTipShown = false;
        }
    }
}
```