# Disabled control Tooltip not working inside Group box in Windows form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, winforms

I am trying to show tooltip of a disable control ..I can do it in form mouse move event even it is working fine

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491267/how-can-i-show-a-tooltip-on-a-disabled-button
```

but when i am doing it for the controls inside a group box it is not working ..

need help

code i am using ..

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var parent = sender as Control;
    if (parent == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    var ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);
    if (ctrl != null && !ctrl.Enabled)
    {
        if (ctrl.Visible && toolTip1.Tag == null)
        {
            var tipstring = "My tooltip";// toolTip1.GetToolTip(ctrl);
            toolTip1.Show(tipstring, ctrl, ctrl.Width / 2, ctrl.Height / 2);
            toolTip1.Tag = ctrl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ctrl = toolTip1.Tag as Control;
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            toolTip1.Hide(ctrl);
            toolTip1.Tag = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Its working when i am placing the control outside the group box but when i am placing the control inside the group box it is not working

I just debugged the code and get that Form1_MouseMove event not working for the controls inside the Groupbox.basically var ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location); it is taking the location of the groupbox not the position of the control inside the group box

Hope can do it using groupBox1_MouseHover ...have anyone used it to get controls of group box.

Comment: I just debugged the code and get that Form1_MouseMove event not working for the controls inside the Groupbox.basically var ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location); it is taking the location of the groupbox not the position of the control inside the group box

Answer (score 0):

You need some `global MouseMove`, try using a `IMessageFilter` like this;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter {
   public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
      Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
   }
   public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m){
     if(m.Msg == 0x200){//WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200
       ShowToolTip(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd));
     }
     return false;
   }
   private void ShowToolTip(Control ctrl){
        if (ctrl != null && !ctrl.Enabled)
        {
            if (ctrl.Visible && toolTip1.Tag == null)
            {
                var tipstring = "My tooltip";// toolTip1.GetToolTip(ctrl);
                toolTip1.Show(tipstring, ctrl, ctrl.Width / 2, ctrl.Height / 2);
                toolTip1.Tag = ctrl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ctrl = toolTip1.Tag as Control;
            if (ctrl != null)
            {
                toolTip1.Hide(ctrl);
                toolTip1.Tag = null;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

**NOTE**: I suppose your original code works OK. Although I think it's not good.

Comment: ..thanks for the code but where have you used PreFilterMessage...how to tag it with that control

Comment: @RahulChowdhury `PreFilterMessage` is not designed for you to `call manually`, it's called automatically by the underlying classes. Have you even tried my code yet?

Comment: @RahulChowdhury I missed a code line in the form constructor, see the update. We need `AddMessageFilter`.

Comment: thanks for your reply ...but its not working ..I took two buttons in a group box.in form load i put button.Enable=false..then i do whatever you did here ..

Comment: I have debugged it ...its not going inside the if (ctrl != null && !ctrl.Enabled) condition ..and what is the use of m.Msg == 0x200?

Comment: @RahulChowdhury does it go inside the `if(m.Msg == 0x200)`?

Answer (score 0):

The GroupBox swallows the MouseMove on the parent form, so the global MouseMove handler of @King King should work, but is a little extreme in that there is a simpler solution.

Even though the designer does not offer the MouseMove event on the groupbox, it is there.

Simply add in the load or shown event (constructor should work too)

```
groupBox.MouseMove += GroupBox_MouseMove;
```

You can also get the tooltip text set originally (e. g. in designer) and set that:

```
string toolTipString = toolTip.GetToolTip(control);
```

If you need this to work both for the parent form as well as the groupbox, you could add the same event handler to multiple controls.