# Tooltip on disabled button

Tags: c#, winforms

I posted this question sometime back and someone marked it as DUPLICATE. But when i asked him questions about the post that supposedly has the answer, he didn't had any proper explanations. So please read this question carefully before marking or down voting.

My question is regarding displaying tooltip on a Button that's DISABLED.

```
this.btnMy.Enabled = false;
```

I have a button which is placed inside a panel with a tooltip associated to it. Now it all works fine when button is enabled.

But if button is **disabled**, then tooltip doesn't work. This seems to be the standard behavior.

Now i want to show the tooltip when button is **disabled** too. So i did the following thing.

```
private ToolTip m_tooltip = new ToolTip();
private bool toolTipShown = false;
private button btnMy;

m_tooltip.InitialDelay = 0;
m_tooltip.ShowAlways = true;

 private void myForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.btnMy == FindControlAtCursor(this))
            {
                if (!toolTipShown)
                {
                    m_tooltip.Show("MyToolTip", this.btnMy, e.Location);
                    toolTipShown = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_tooltip.Hide(this.btnGiven);
                toolTipShown = false;
            }
        }
```

As the button is inside a panel, i had to use couple other functions to find the exact button control when mouse is over it.

```
public static Control FindControlAtPoint(Control container, Point pos)
        {
            Control child;
            foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
            {
                if (c.Visible && c.Bounds.Contains(pos))
                {
                    child = FindControlAtPoint(c, new Point(pos.X - c.Left, pos.Y - c.Top));
                    if (child == null) return c;
                    else return child;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static Control FindControlAtCursor(Form form)
        {
            Point pos = Cursor.Position;
            if (form.Bounds.Contains(pos))
                return FindControlAtPoint(form, form.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
            return null;
        }
```

Now when i debug, i can see the code finding the right button and trying to call ToolTip.Show, but for some reason it's not getting displayed.

While debugging, i see a small tooltip pop up. Other wise in release mode, nothing gets shown at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: The top _Related_ question on the right side is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491267/how-can-i-show-a-tooltip-on-a-disabled-button?rq=1). Are the answers to that question inapplicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to argue whether it's a duplicate or not (although as [HABO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92546/habo) pointed out in the comments it looks pretty similar to [How can I show a tooltip on a disabled button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491267/how-can-i-show-a-tooltip-on-a-disabled-button?rq=1)). Also I'm not going to discuss the code in whole.

The main problem is in this line

```
m_tooltip.Show("MyToolTip", this.btnMy, e.Location);
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44atyhsa(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `ToolTip.Show` overload that you are using states for the `point` argument

> A Point containing the offset, in pixels, relative to the upper-left corner of the associated control window, to display the ToolTip.

while you are passing a point relative to the form.

In order to fix it, you should use something like this

```
var pos = this.btnMy.PointToClient(this.PointToScreen(e.Location));
m_tooltip.Show("MyToolTip", this.btnMy, pos);
```

Comment: I am not sure what's going on. As i explained in the question, when i debug through the code, i can see the tooltip pop up. But when running the app outside debugger, it doesn't show up. Isn't that strange?

Comment: @don I've tried it and it works in both VS and exe(Release mode). But if I put the button inside a Panel, it doesn't work in both scenarious, because apparently the form does not receive MouseMove, but Panel. Are you sure the cause of the problem you are experiencing is not so trivial, i.e need hooking into a panel `MouseMove` event?

Comment: Should hook the MouseMove event to Panel? Will that work?

Comment: I believe so. You can check inside simply if `btnMy.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)` and then use `var pos = this.btnMy.PointToClient((Panel)sender).PointToScreen(e.Location));`

Comment: That works! You saved my day.....Awesome.... There's a problem with tooltip not showing on the bottom tip of mouse cursor. That's the only issue am seeing now. It's shown on one side of cursor.

Answer (score 2):

The MouseMove event won't fire when the mouse is over child controls or panels, so you are much better off using a Timer instead:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Control c = FindControlAtPoint(this, this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));
  if (c != null) {
    Point p = c.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    p.Offset(10, 10);
    m_tooltip.Show("Found " + c.Name, c, p);
    m_tooltip.Active = true;
  } else {
    m_tooltip.Active = false;
  }
}
```