# show tooltip on disabled button inside multiple controls

Tags: vb.net

I would like to display the tooltip on a disabled button, I've tried the code below but it looks not to be working. 
I think that's because the button is inside a group box and the group box inside a panel, the panel is inside the form.
the code reported would work only if the button is directly on the form..

```
Private toolTipShown As Boolean = False

Private Sub TimeWorks_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    Dim parent = TryCast(sender, Control)

    If parent Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim ctrl = parent.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location)

    If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then

        If ctrl.Visible AndAlso toolTip1.Tag Is Nothing Then

            If Not toolTipShown Then
                Dim tipstring = toolTip1.GetToolTip(ctrl)
                toolTip1.Show(tipstring.Trim(), ctrl, ctrl.Width / 2, ctrl.Height / 2)
                toolTip1.Tag = ctrl
                toolTipShown = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
        ctrl = TryCast(toolTip1.Tag, Control)

        If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then
            toolTip1.Hide(ctrl)
            toolTip1.Tag = Nothing
            toolTipShown = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions to make the code working?

Comment: Maybe you can try this. Don't actually disable the button. Juat remove the Event Handlers attached to it and vice versa when enabling it.

Comment: @preciousbetine I have thought about that, but the user expects something to happen if the button is clickable..

Comment: Well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407146/tooltip-on-disabled-button) improves the original c# code in [How can I show a tooltip on a disabled button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491267/how-can-i-show-a-tooltip-on-a-disabled-button?rq=1)